# Failed sending email with java program via smtp and ssl

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am just trying to send an email form java code. But I am getting exception like this:

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: 
 Could not connect to SMTP host:smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1."
```

I have set the following properties:

```
mail.smtp.host
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port
mail.smtp.auth
mail.smtp.port
```

What is the reason for this exception?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have internet in application running server ?

Comment: He's probably accessing Stackoverflow by USPS.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try this example to sort it out problem -

[Java send mail through gmail](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

Comment: Yes I am getting the same exception with this program too.

Comment: Try ping `smtp.gmail.com` and make sure you got a response (able to access). Often times, your connection may block by your firewall or proxy behind

Comment: ping works fine. The same program works fine on friend's system and firewall also stopped in my system.

Comment: ok. get your proxy server addrs and port and set it by `System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.mydomain.com");
System.setPropery("http.proxyPort", "8080");`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't found the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).  These entries might help:

- [How do I debug problems connecting to my mail server?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug)
- [How do I configure JavaMail to work through my proxy server?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy)